# Why Entity Framework does't Delete the entity when I remove it from navigation property collection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

While learning EF, happened to see link [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx), need two small clarifications regarding the below code

```
// Currently, the Entity Framework doesn’t mark the entities  
// that are removed from a navigation property (in our example the Products) 
// as deleted in the context.  
// The following code uses LINQ to Objects against the Local collection  
// to find all products and marks any that do not have 
// a Category reference as deleted.  
// The ToList call is required because otherwise  
// the collection will be modified  
// by the Remove call while it is being enumerated.  
// In most other situations you can do LINQ to Objects directly  
// against the Local property without using ToList first. 
foreach (var product in _context.Products.Local.ToList()) 
{ 
    if (product.Category == null) 
    { 
        _context.Products.Remove(product); 
    } 
} 

// Save the changes to the database. 
this._context.SaveChanges();
```

1  when we delete a child item which is product(nav property of category) from a  category, the product.category becoming null. we are deleting the product(nav of category) and how entity frame work marks category as null in local collection Products.

2  Is there any other options to delete nav property other than enumerating the entire collection ?, if No can we only loop through the item under this particular category to avoid performance issues, how can we change the "foreach (var product in _context.Products.Local.ToList()) " to loop only the item under this category.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your problem is. 1. *product.category becoming null* So what? You're deleting it anyway. 2. *this particular category* Which category? You're deleting products *without* a category.

Comment: The code serves an important goal: detecting which products should be deleted. To find out why such code is written read the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The code serves an important goal: detecting which products should be deleted. To find out why such code is written read the answer below.

**What does Entity Framework do when I remove an entity from navigation property collection?**

Entity Framework doesn't mark the entities that are removed from a navigation property collection as deleted in the context. It just removes the entity from navigation property collection and cut the relation by setting the parent navigation property of the entity to null and make the child orphan.

It's because you just removed the entity from navigation property collection not from entity set. Removing them from navigation property means only cutting the relation.

For example if you have a N-N relation between categories and products which each category may have 0 or N products and each product may belongs to 0 or N categories. Then if you remove a product from navigation property collection of a category, you don't want to delete the product, you only want removing the product from that category, but the product and its relations which other categories should remain untouched.

**How can I find orphan entities?**

Orphan child entities have parent property with null value. They are still present in local storage of entity set of child entities. So you can find them and mark them for delete.

In the article example in a 1-N relation between categories and products, each product belongs to a category and removing it from products collection of a category means deleting it, so in such case when you remove a product from child collection of a category, your goal is deleting the product. So you should check in `Local` storage of `Products` and find all products which their `Catergory` is `null` and mark theme for delete.

**Your questions**

1. As mentioned above, EF sets the category property of a product to null, when you remove the product from products collection of the category. This way EF cuts the relation.
2. While the current solution is OK, but yes, there is other solutions too. Since `Products` property of `Category` is of type of `ObservableCollection<T>`, you can subscribe to its `CollectionChanged` event and detect deleting product and there you can remove product from context.
   But looping through `Products` of current category is useless, because the product is removed from there.